# Help on understanding the proof of measurability of a function specifying only a class of sets that generates the Borel sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation

The following question might be too easy for many people and concerns about a very basic doubt, which I am sure I am missing somehow, but I will be glad if someone could help me a little clarifying my confusion.

Let $\mathcal{B}$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $(S,\Sigma)$ be a measurable space with the set of all $\Sigma$-measurable functions denoted by $m\Sigma$. Then, the proposition 3.2 (b) of the book **Probability with Martingales** by David Williams states the following

> Let $\mathcal{C}\subseteq \mathcal{B}$ and $\sigma(\mathcal{C})=\mathcal{B}$. Then $h^{-1}:\mathcal{C}\to \Sigma$ implies that $h\in m\Sigma$.

The proof proceeds by showing that the class of sets $\mathcal{A}=\{A\in \mathcal{B}:h^{-1}(A)\in \Sigma\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{C}$ and therefore is equal to $\mathcal{B}$, establishing the desired result. While the proof is very easy, I am confused to see that during the proof the author does not show that $\mathbb{R}\in \mathcal{A}$, or equivalently, $\emptyset\in \mathcal{A}$. 
I have also seen the same kind of proof in quite a few other books, which means there must be something trivial about this, but I don't understand how to show that $h^{-1}(\mathbb{R})\in \Sigma$ or, equivalently, $h^{-1}(\emptyset)\in \Sigma$ unless $\mathbb{R}\in \mathcal{C}$ or $\emptyset \in \mathcal{C}$. Is it somehow related to the fact that $\sigma(\mathcal{C})=\mathcal{B}$? Can somebody help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: what IS $h^{-1}(\mathbb R)$, or $h^{-1}(\varnothing)$, exactly?

Comment: $h^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ should be $S$, but since the domain of $h^{-1}$ is $\mathcal{C}$, if $\mathbb{R}\notin\mathcal{C}$, $h^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ is undefined right?

Comment: $h^{-1}(A)$ is defined for any subset $A$ (otherwise how would you even define measurability, or formulate your question?). Writing $h^{-1}:\mathcal C\to\Sigma$ means that every set in $\mathcal C$ is sent to $\Sigma$, but $h^{-1}(\mathbb R)$ is still defined, and even if $\mathbb R$ is not in $\mathcal C$, its preimage is $S$, as you said, and belongs to $\Sigma$.

Comment: Ohh, okay. So $h$ is taken to be such a function that the domain of $h^{-1}$ is *all* of $\mathcal{B}$. The notation $h^{-1}:\mathcal{C}\to \Sigma$ is then misleading, don't you think?

Comment: I don't find it particularly misleading, because $h^{-1}$ is always well-defined on all of $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ actually. For instance, the definition of $h$ being measurable is that $h^{-1}$ maps $\mathcal B$ into $\Sigma$, so $h^{-1}:\mathcal B\to\Sigma$ makes sense as a restriction but the notation $h^{-1}$ itself was defined before, so it feels natural to me to keep the same notation for $h^{-1}(A)$, whether $A$ is measurable or not.

Comment: Moreover, in the sentence you quote, you say "Then $h^{-1}:\mathcal C\to\Sigma$ implies [...]", so grammatically "$h^{-1}:\mathcal C\to\Sigma$" has to be a *property,* not a *definition.* And if it was a definition, you'd have to define $h^{-1}(A)$ again, for sets in $\mathcal C$.

Comment: @PierrePC Thanks a lot for the clarifications!

Answer (score 0):

$\mathcal{A}$ contains $\emptyset$ because $h^{-1}[\emptyset] = \emptyset \in \Sigma$ ($\sigma$ being a $\sigma$-algebra) and also $h^{-1}[\Bbb R]=S \in \Sigma$ as well. Just basic set theory.

Comment: Actually my main doubt was whether $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are within the domain of $h^{-1}$, but as @Pierre PC explained in the comments, the domain of $h^{-1}$ contains all of $\mathcal{B}$, which makes things very trivial.